# iOS + Jenkins + git + Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, git, jenkins, archive

I use the Jenkins iOS Archive.
The jenkins project Console Output:

```
/bin/sh -c /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/YouKuHD/workspace/frameworks/download/build/DownloadManager.build/Debug-iphoneos/DownloadManager.build/Script-DB597F9F14DFD58700CDF0E3.sh
Could not find iphoneos in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/YouKuHD/workspace/build
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

```
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script build/DownloadManager.build/Debug-iphoneos/DownloadManager.build/Script-DB597F9F14DFD58700CDF0E3.sh

(1 failure)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

My project files:

> iPad28/frameworks/download/DownloadManager.xcodeproj
> iPad28/frameworks/youku.coreYouku.xcodeproj
>
> iPad28/ipad/YouKuHD.xcodeproj

Xcode configuration：

> Advanced Xcode build options

Xcode Project File

> ipad/YouKuHD.xcodeproj

What should I do?

I make a test project also failed

The following build commands failed:

Check dependencies

(1 failure)

Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE

What should I do?